# Remove Node from list animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have list of html nodes (divs, with float left)

```
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

I want to remove a node say 4, all the nodes after 4, i.e. here 5,6,7 should move left slowly.

Is there any way I can do this?

PS: I have only jquery in the project as long as possible I want to keep that way without including much libraries.

Comment: A list of nodes? Are you talking about an array? And what should move slowly? You question isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry, My apologies. I have html div elements, I want to remove it and divs after that animate and occupy the position of the removed div.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: Bingo, thats exactly what I want to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
    <div id="3">3</div>
    <div id="4">4</div>
    <div id="5">5</div>
    <div id="6">6</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).hide( 2000, function() {
    $( this ).remove();
  });
});
```

And **CSS:**

```
div {
background: green;
width: 30px;
height: 40px;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
color:white
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pawankullu/ppj9sjb0/)

Answer (score 1):

Use http://api.jquery.com/hide/ . Look to examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [jQuery.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
 Try this-

```
   $("#4").hide('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
```

**Update:-**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/0vogmj3c/)

Answer (score 1):

I just create some sample with jQuery's animate API.

Following sample may be help you.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jckim0414/6gfdukdq/)

Anybody help me fsfiddle link

html

```
<p><button id="go">Run »</button></p>
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
    <div class="block">3</div>
    <div class="block">4</div>
    <div class="block">5</div>
    <div class="block">6</div>
    <div class="block">7</div>
```

css

```
div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #abc;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

js

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
    $( ".block:nth(3)" ).css("visibility","hidden");
    $( ".block:nth(3)" ).animate({
        left: -50
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function( now, fx ){
            $( ".block:gt(3)" ).css( "left", now );
        }
    }); 
});
```